# Can VB.NET specify the size of an array parameter?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, parameters, pass-by-reference

I want to create a function that takes an argument of a reference to an array of at least a certain length, so that the function will know that there is enough space for it to write all the data it needs to write to the array.

Is this possible in VB.NET?

At the moment I am `ReDim`'ing the referenced array but I'm not sure if this is really working or not. (I guess I can test this method and break it by passing an array to small and see, will try that momentarily)

```
Public Function Foo(ByRef data() As Byte) As Boolean
    If Data.Length < 4 Then
        ReDim Preserve ProductId(4)
    End If
    ' Other operations that put 4 bytes on the array...
    Return True
End Function
```

Even if that method works, I'm not convinced that re-sizing the users array is really that great of an idea in comparison to just informing them that the parameter specifies a length of 4 somehow... Is there a better way of managing this?

Comment: It looks like maybe the function "does too much".  It apparently finds/gets the array of bytes but *also* returns a bool indicating something else. If/when there is no data or other failure nothing to return, return an empty array to signal failure or no data available.  It seems too ambitious the way it is, given what little we know.

Comment: You've got a point, @Plutonix. It might be better to use a struct for this, and then have the boolean function take the struct.

Comment: @Plutonix the function interacts with a H/W device that returns data on the COM port of varying un-fixed lengths, some or all of which may be zero. The boolean indicates if the communication failed or was cancelled for some reason (e.g. COM isn't set up correctly yet) in which case the array will still be all zero, but not because the data returned was zero, so there needs to be some way of discerning the difference.

Comment: @MichaelMcPherson Good suggestion, I've been shying away from it though as the H/W I'm interacting with has a ton of settings I want to write "setter" functions for to treat them as if they were properties. Having a different struct for each of the different setting types would make the class very cluttered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No as far as I know you can't specify the size of the array in the parameters list.

You can however, check the size of the array like you are currently doing and then throw an ArgumentException.  This seems to be one of the most common ways to validate data at the start of a method.

Answer (score 3):

Your function should take in a stream instead.

```
Public Function Foo(ByVal stream As Stream) As Boolean
    'Write bytes to stream
End Function
```

For eaxmple you can call your method using a `MemoryStream`

```
Dim stream = new MemoryStream()
Foo(stream)
Dim array = stream.ToArray() 'Call ToArray to get an array from the stream.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate some? I've not used streams before can you recommend a reading resource on using them in this, or a similar manner? Ta

Comment: In the case of a Memory stream it is just an auto growing byte array.

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually try something similar to what you're doing here, but like this:

```
Public Function Foo(ByRef data() As Byte) As Boolean
 If Data.Length < 4 Then
    Return False
 End If

 'Other operations...

  Return True
End Function
```

Or maybe this:

```
Public Function Foo(ByRef data() As Byte) As String
 If Data.Length < 4 Then
    Return "This function requires an array size of four"
 End If

 'Other operations...

  Return "True"
End Function
```

Then, in your calling function, this:

```
Dim d As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(Foo(YourArray))
```

Then you can bubble up the error to the user, which is what you were looking to do, right?

Comment: OK, I didn't know this was possible (I usually program in C, where converting a string to a boolean would be nearly laughable :) ), I'll give it a whirl

Comment: I'm usually in C# or PHP, where polymorphism is a snap. I had to look up how to do it in VB.NET ;)

Comment: Please throw an error (as Chris suggested) instead of this, this isn't going to make your code any more readable to other people (or yourself in 6 months) and is generally just misusing the string return type to do two things at once (error handling and returning values)